# JS Lint for Visual Studio 2010 problems

Tags: javascript, jshint

I have a file with a JS object:

```
function Monitor() {

var self = this;
...
```

And I have a file that creates an instance of this and uses it.

```
self.monitor = new Monitor();
```

The files are included in a cshtml file in order:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Shared/Monitor.js")"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Views/NewMonitor_Index.js")"></script>
```

The problem is I get this error:

```
Warning 1 JS Hint: 'Monitor' is not defined.
```

How do I configure it so that it finds the monitor object?

Comment: I don't know if there is an automatic way, but if I know that a certain symbol is definitely available in the context, I add a `/*global Monitor*/` at the beginning of the script.

Comment: Why do you care about the warning if you know it's defined in a place `jshint` can't reach?

Comment: It's in my app so I assumed JS Hint could reach it.  And I don't really want warnings that don't mean anything - too much clutter.

Comment: Thanks Felix - that did the trick - Could you post it as the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think if there is an automatic way. Although JSHint could detect other script tags, it is probably more difficult to get the actual path to the file.

Anyways, if I know that a certain symbol is definitely available in the context, I add a

```
/*global Monitor*/
```

at the beginning of the script.

If a symbol will be available in every script, I add it to my `.jshintrc` file in the directory, like

```
{
    "predef": [
        "Monitor"
    ]
}
```

But I don't know if/how this works on Windows.